# Check if string contains all strings from array

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to check if `String` contains all `Strings` from `Array`.

My current code:

```
String word = "abc";
String[] keywords = {"a", "d"};

for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    if(word.contains(keywords[i])){
       System.out.println("Yes");
    }else{
       System.out.println("No");   
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code would look much more nicer if you wrap it into a separate method:

```
public static boolean containsAllWords(String word, String ...keywords) {
    for (String k : keywords)
        if (!word.contains(k)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Java 8+, you could use a `Stream` and test if all of the elements match your criteria with one line. Like,

```
if (Stream.of(keywords).allMatch(word::contains)) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

In earlier versions, or if you want to understand what the above is doing, it might look something like

```
boolean allMatch = true;
for (String kw : keywords) {  // <-- for each kw in keywords
    if (!word.contains(kw)) { // <-- if "word" doesn't contain kw
        allMatch = false;     // <-- set allMatch to false
        break;                // <-- stop checking
    }
}
if (allMatch) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `boolean` variable that will tell you if every keyword is matched. Set it to `true` as default value. Then check every keword: if any one is not contained in your word, stop searching and set your variable to `false`.

```
boolean containsAll = true; 
for (String keyword : keywords){
    if (!word.contains(keyword)){
       containsAll = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer this over having multiple return statements. Small changes though,

boolean containsAll; 
for (String keyword : keywords){
    containsAll = word.contains(keyword);
    if (!containsAll){
       break;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

**Note** this solution work only if your keywords contain ***one char***, there are many answers already mentioned if your keywords contain more then one char.

**With one line :**

```
boolean contain = Arrays.asList(word.split("")).containsAll(Arrays.asList(keywords));
```

---

The idea is :

```
String word = "abc";
String[] split = word.split("");
```

Split your String to get an array of chars `split = {a, b, c}`

```
String[] keywords = {"a", "b"};
```

Check if your `array1` contain all the element of the second `array2` using `containsAll`

```
boolean contain = Arrays.asList(split).containsAll(Arrays.asList(keywords));
```

Comment: @CoronA but the OP's example contain one letter and not two like you do

Comment: @JCF: Algorithms usually do not solve examples but problems.

Comment: @CoronA i think that note now, fix every thing no? check my edit :)

Answer (score -1):

Either use StringUtils (`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`). It will return the index of the first occurrence of keywords or -1 if it is not there.

```
StringUtils.indexOfAny(word, keywords);
```

Or you can use `Arrays` which will return the boolean value.

```
Arrays.asList(word).contains(keywords)
```

Comment: There is a method StringUtils::containsAny, however OP needs the check against all search strings.
Arrays.asList(word) will return a list with only the single element word. The method Collections::contains can not receive an array. Though there is the method Collections::containsAll. This doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use a counter:

```
String word = "abc";
String[] keywords = {"a", "d"};

int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    if(word.contains(keywords[i])){
       counter++;
    }
}

if(counter == keywords.length){
   System.out.println("Yes");
}else{
   System.out.println("No");   
}
```

If the counter equals the keywords length, it means that all elements are contained. With this solution you will also be able to find out how many keywords are matched by the word.

Comment: I don't get what you mean sorry

Answer (score -2):

A better code would be:

```
for(String s: keywords){
    if(word.contains(s)){
       System.out.println("Yes");
    }else{
       System.out.println("No");   
    }
}
```

Comment: You forget the break statement.

Comment: before commenting please make sure your code is correct and also care to explain your.