# Simple java pattern matching issue?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to test if a string contains `insert` and `name`, with any interceding characters. And if it does, I would like to print the match.

For the below code, only the third `Pattern` matches, and the entire line is printed. How can I match only `insert...name`?

```
    String x = "aaa insert into name sdfdf";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("insert.*name").matcher(x);
    if (matcher.matches()) 
        System.out.print(matcher.group(0));  
    matcher = Pattern.compile(".*insert.*name").matcher(x);
    if (matcher.matches()) 
        System.out.print(matcher.group(0));  
    matcher = Pattern.compile(".*insert.*name.*").matcher(x);
    if (matcher.matches()) 
        System.out.print(matcher.group(0));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains all strings from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409630/check-if-string-contains-all-strings-from-array)

Comment: Why not just use `insert.*name`? If that matches, it's in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use group like this `.*(insert.*name).*`

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*(insert.*name).*").matcher(x);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
    //-----------------------------^
}
```

Or in your case you can just use :

```
x = x.replaceAll(".*(insert.*name).*", "$1");
```

Both of them print :

```
insert into name
```

Comment: If that's the case, why not just match `insert.*name`?

Comment: @ctwheels if you use `insert.*name` what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result would be exactly that: `insert into name`

Comment: @YCF_L thanks, any suggestion how to make this work if `x` contains new line characters? `y = "\n aaa insert into name sdfdf \n";`

Comment: @ab11 Use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)

Comment: @ctwheels i don't think this is correct, If i understand your suggest I can write this demo https://ideone.com/ysiUeS

Comment: @ab11 correct as @ctwheets mention you can use `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*(insert.*name).*", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(x);`

Comment: @YCF_L It does work: https://ideone.com/5wanDH. Also see anubhava's answer for the same code.

Comment: aah you use `matcher.group(0)` yes you are correct ;)

Comment: @YCF_L you also need to use `.find()` instead of `.matches()`

Comment: @ctwheels already anubhava do all what you said in his answer ';(, but I still want to go with the second solution instead

Comment: @YCF_L @ctwheels, when I add `Pattern.DOTALL`, I get match if a `\n` occurs between `insert` and `name`, can I match this: `"\n aaa insert into name sdfdf \n";` but not `"\n aaa insert into \n name sdfdf \n";`?

Comment: @ab11 you can enable/disable flags within the pattern itself: `insert(?s).*(?-s)name` or just use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `find()` instead of `matches()` in your code:

```
String x = "aaa insert into name sdfdf";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("insert.*?name").matcher(x);
if (matcher.find()) 
    System.out.print(matcher.group(0));
```

`matches()` expects you to match entire input string whereas `find()` lets you match your regex anywhere in the input.

Also suggest you to use `.*?` instead of `.*`, in case your input may contain multiple instances of `index ... name` pairs.

This code sample will output:

```
insert into name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple positive lookaheads:

```
(?=.*insert)(?=.*name).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XYvxCB/1).